# Ng2-smart table get selected rows using checkbox

Tags: angular

i am using angular 2 with ng2-smarttable.

I add checkbox in table.Here is my code.

```
settings = {
    mode:"external",
    selectMode: 'multi',
    columns: {
       Check:{
        title: '',
        type: 'html',
        valuePrepareFunction: (value) => { return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.input); },
        filter: false
       },
       orderby:{
        title: "Name",
        filter: true
       }
 }
```

it's works.But i need get checkbox with event and get selected row.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/181

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add "userRowSelect" event your HTML code as below.

```
 <ng2-smart-table class="table table-bordered" [settings]="settings" [source]="data" (create)="onAdd($event)"
             (delete)="onDelete($event)" (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)">
 </ng2-smart-table>
```

Add your method as below and it will return all selected rows.

```
public onUserRowSelect(event) {
  var selectedRows = event.selected;
}
```